# Make pandas.qcut output compatible to scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, binning

From **scipy** reference for [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd.html),

> Binedges: All but the last (righthand-most) bin is half-open in each
> dimension. In other words, if bins is [1, 2, 3, 4], then the first bin
> is [1, 2) (including 1, but excluding 2) and the second [2, 3). The
> last bin, however, is [3, 4], which includes 4.

I want to use [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) to generate the bin edges to pass to binned statistic, but the edges are defined exactly the other way around.

```
a = np.arange(0,10,1)

[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

where,

```
d,b = pd.qcut(a, 9, retbins=True)
print(d.value_counts())
print(b)

(-0.001, 1.0]    2
(1.0, 2.0]       1
(2.0, 3.0]       1
(3.0, 4.0]       1
(4.0, 5.0]       1
(5.0, 6.0]       1
(6.0, 7.0]       0
(7.0, 8.0]       2
(8.0, 9.0]       1
dtype: int64
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
```

If I now run the `binned_statistic` using this binning,

```
h,e,binning = sp.stats.binned_statistic_dd(values=a,sample=a,bins=[np.array(b)])
print(binning)
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9]
```

which is a different binning of course, due to the different definition of the bin edges.

Is there a way to the the edges of `qcut` reversed? since are "real" numbers I cannot just shift the values.
Otherwise, does scipy has this capability in some way I cannot see? Does binned_statistic allow to  automatically define the bins based on the data distribution somehow?

So, expected output (is not uniquely defined) for this particular case could be

```
be = [0, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8.5, 9.5]
```

such that,

```
h,e,binning = sp.stats.binned_statistic_dd(values=a,sample=a,bins=[np.array(be)])

print(binning)
[1 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 8 9]
```

Comment: expected output?

Comment: Added the expected output, thanks for the heads up.